# Parse.com PHP SDK Class Error when including page

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm getting the following error in my Parse application, in PHP:

> Fatal error: Class 'ParseQuery' not found in settings.php

The way I have my files setup is that all of my Parse code is in **index.php**, and that file "includes" other files based on the requested "page".

Example:

**index.php**

```
<?php

// define location of Parse PHP SDK
define( 'PARSE_SDK_DIR', 'src/Parse/' );

// include Parse SDK autoloader
require_once( 'autoload.php' );

// Start session
session_start();

// Add the "use" declarations where you'll be using the classes
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud; 
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

//Initialize Parse
ParseClient::initialize( 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz' );

//Check if the user is logged in
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
if(!$currentUser){ header("Location: login.php"); }

// Load initial config & settins
require_once('settings.php');

?>
```

**settings.php**

```
<?php

//General Settings
$query = new ParseQuery("Website_Settings");

try {
    $settings = $query->find();
    foreach($settings as $setting){
        $config[$setting->get('name')] = $setting->get('value');
    }
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'load.php');
}
catch (ParseException $ex) {
    print 'There was an error! Please forward this error to your system administrator: <br>'.$ex;
}

?>
```

Should the included file settings.php not have access to the Parse classes and initiated session in index.php?